# Implement the number of likes on the post in the template

Tags: python, django

I am struggling with implementing a working like button. I think I have the code for it, but I don't get how to implement it in the template.

(would this be a proper way to make the like button, so if anyone else watch this question, they can get help as well, for what the best way to make like button)

do know that I am aware that I will have to use Ajax at some point, but my focus right now is just to get that number of likes displayed next to the like button.

models.py

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    post = models.CharField(max_length=3000) #probably switch to a textfield
    sender = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='sent_the_post', null=True, blank=True)
    sent = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    read = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False, null=True, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-timestamp']

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.post

class Like(models.Model):
    liked_users = models.ManyToManyField(User, null=True, blank=True, related_name='liked_users')
    post = models.ForeignKey(Posts, null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'like'
```

views.py

```
def like(request):    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST['post_id']
        try:
            post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        except:
            post = None
        if post:
            post_to_like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(post=post)
            if request.user in post_to_like.liked_users:
                #this removes the user
                post_to_like.liked_users.remove(request.user)
            else:
                post_to_like.liked_users.add(request.user)

            post_to_like.save()
            like_count = post_to_like.liked_users.count() #returns number of users in the manytomanyfield

    return render_to_response('posts/wall.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

wall.html template - the below is in the post div

```
<form action='' method='post'> {% csrf_token %}
    <input name='post_id' value='{{ post.id }}' type='hidden' />
    <input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Like'>
    </form>

    {{ .like_count }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the number of likes next to the button in the template:

```
<input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Like' /> {{post.like_set.count}} likes
```

Or using the [pluralisation template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#pluralize) (so you get `1 like` and `2 likes` etc):

```
{% with post.like_set.count as likes %}
<input class='btn btn-default' type='submit' value='Like'> {{likes}} like{{likes|pluralize}}
{% endwith %}
```